# How to represent Json objects with mixed datatypes in Java with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having a little difficulty serializing some Json into a Java object. As you can see, the Json bit contains the top-level element `args` with a list of objects that contain a `String` as keys and mixed bag of values. I tried some creative things in my Java source file:

**Json**

```
{
    "args": {
        "all": {
            "expectCliArgs": true
        },
        "Prog3a": {
            "expectedNumberOfCliArgs": 2,
            "expectedErrorMessage": "Usage: java Prog3a infilename searchword"
        },
        "Prog3b": {
            "expectedNumberOfCliArgs": 2,
            "expectedErrorMessage": "Usage: java Prog3b infileName outfileName"
        },
        "Prog3c": {
            "expectedNumberOfCliArgs": 1,
            "expectedErrorMessage": "Usage: java Prog3c infileName"
        }
    }
}
```

**Java**

```
protected class Args {
    public Map<String, Set<Map<String, Object>>> map = new HashMap<>(); // no dice
}

protected class Args {
    public Map<String, Set<Map<String, ?>>> map = new HashMap<>(); // no dice
}
```

Is it possible that I need a [custom serializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer)?

**Update**
I tried doing the following in my class (per SO answer):

```
private Map<String, Set<ExpectedArgs>> args = new HashMap<>();

protected class ExpectedArgs {
    public Boolean expectCliArgs;
    public Integer expectedNumberOfCliArgs;
    public String expectedArgsErrorMessage;
}
```

but now it appears as though Gson is complaining about the syntax of my Json file:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 847
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
    at javaGrader.config.ParseConfig.convertJsonToObject(ParseConfig.java:72)
    at javaGrader.config.ParseConfig.parseConfig(ParseConfig.java:34)
    at javaGrader.JavaGrader.main(JavaGrader.java:60)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62344', transport: 'socket'
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 847
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:338)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    ... 7 more
```

I set some break points in my Json file and it looks like the "args" object is the one causing the heartburn. For reference, here's the [full Json file](http://hastebin.com/hoduhuguli.json), [java Config class](http://hastebin.com/hedifaviwi.java), and [the class where Gson runs](http://hastebin.com/agiyupilud.java). It looks like Gson is confusing my object with an Array.

Col 847 is:

```
searchword"},"Prog3b":{
             ^
```

Any ideas?

[image: Gson error]

**Update 2**
My signature for the variable was incorrect:

```
private Map<String, Set<ExpectedArgs>> args = new HashMap<>();  // wrong
private Map<String, ExpectedArgs> args = new HashMap<>(); // right
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a class for the inner objects that contains both sets of fields, like this:

```
public static class ExpectedArgs {
    public Boolean expectCliArgs;
    public Integer expectedNumberOfCliArgs;
    public String expectedErrorMessage;
}
```

(Note I have deliberate used `Boolean` and `Integer` instead of `boolean` and `int` here, such that you can tell whether the field was set by testing for `null`.)

Then you can define the outer class like this:

```
public static class Data {
    public Map<String, ExpectedArgs> args;
}
```

Finally you can deserialize the JSON into an instance of `Data`:

```
String json = "...";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

data.args.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(value.expectCliArgs);
    System.out.println(value.expectedNumberOfCliArgs);
    System.out.println(value.expectedErrorMessage);
    System.out.println();
});
```

This code outputs the following for your example JSON:

```
all
true
null
null

Prog3a
null
2
Usage: java Prog3a infilename searchword

Prog3b
null
2
Usage: java Prog3b infileName outfileName

Prog3c
null
1
Usage: java Prog3c infileName
```

Comment: This is a great solution! I ended up doing this exact thing last night but I encountered an error with Gson. Any ideas?